# Convert image (200x200px) to font using gulp.js

Tags: javascript, image, svg, gulp, task-runner-explorer

I would like to convert png/img to font (safari) using gulp.js.
How I should do it ?
I know that gulp.js helps convert svg -> font.
But I dont know how to convert img -> svg using gulp.js.

Comment: Check this out: https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/

Comment: I edit post , I mean javascript

Comment: It could be hard to find such script since it doesn't make much sense to convert bitmap image to a vector image svg since it would result in a bitmap image being embedded in some svg wrapper.